# GAMESS Gaussian qst2 method alternative

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I've heard about the qst2 Gaussian method but I don't have any licence so I use the free GAMESS-US. Nevertheless, I didn't find any Gamess method which allows a TS finding like qst2. Have you heard about an alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't tend to use the QST2 method in gaussian but perhaps the Nudged Elastic Band approach that has been implemented in ORCA 4.1 may be of some use. It too takes the structure of both the reactant and product as inputs. ORCA is free for academic use unless the licencing has changed recently. https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/geometry-optimizations/tutorial-neb-calculations

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, looks like a new and good alternative !

Comment: I'd also recommend the growing string method. We've recently implemented it into python https://github.com/ZimmermanGroup/pyGSM. It doesn't have Gaussian hooked up right now but it's fairly easy to do that. Orca works with it.